# Why this time complexity is not a valid answer?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

We are working on a solver for a problem having next open question:

*Is possible to implement a solver for the problem in time $O(2^{(1-\epsilon) \cdot \frac{n}{2}})$, for some $\epsilon>0$*

And we implemented a solver in time $O(2^{(1-\frac{4}{n}) \cdot \frac{n}{2}})$

When checking this result with the question's author, he stated this time does not answer the question without further explanation, even when $\frac{4}{n}$ is $> 0$ for all $n > 0$.

I accept his answer, but I would like to understand why is not valid so we can try a different approach that could answer the questions properly.

Comment: $O(2^{(1-\frac4n)\frac n2})=O(2^{\frac n2-2})=O(2^{\frac n2})$, which would require $\varepsilon=0$. I think the author had a constant $\varepsilon$ in mind

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, however from my point of view if $\epsilon = 0.001$ and $n=6000$ basically the author is expecting to solve the problem by brute force by 'just' processing the $1.5$ percent from the possible values to verify, and the percentage gets smaller as $n$ increases, making it more unlikely... this is why I posted the question here, to try to understand what I'm missing

Comment: If you divide the exponent by $n/2$, the result should be away from $1$ by a fixed constant margin; $1 - 4/n$ is not. $2^{(1 - 4/n) n/2} \neq O(2^{(1 - \epsilon) n/2})$ because you can't choose a constant $M$ s.t. $2^{(1 - 4/n) n/2} \leq M \cdot 2^{(1 - \epsilon) n/2}$ holds for all large enough $n$.

Comment: Maxim thanks for the extended description, and I agree as well with you.